# Getting empty JSON from nconfig with express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

Im using flatiron/nconf for my application configuration. I have create a application in expressjs and with nconf.

getting empty JSON body.

File: configutil.js

```
'use strict';
var fs    = require('fs'),
    nconf = require('nconf');

    nconf.argv()
    .env()
    .file({ file : __dirname + '/config/app.json' });

    nconf.defaults({
    'http': {
        'port': 1337
    }
});
```

File: util/index.js

```
exports.configutil = require('./configutil');
```

File: app.js

```
var util        = require('./util');
var config      = util.configutil;
console.log(config);
```

Console log print empty JSON body.

Comment: But configutil.js does not export anything

Comment: export in index.js by require the configutil.js

Comment: Yes, but you need an `exports.* =` somewhere in `configutil.js` too.

Comment: Change the code as below but still I am not getting my JSON value
var settings;

settings = (function() {
  var publicSettings, realSettings;
  realSettings = __dirname + "/config/app.json";
  if (fs.existsSync(realSettings)) {
   nconf.argv()
 .env()
 .file('file', {
      file: realSettings
    });
  } 
  nconf.load();
  return nconf;
})();

module.exports = settings;